# Add an OpenGraph tag in WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have to add Product SKU to Woocommerce metatags product page (Facebook OpenGraph). I've tried to add

```
global $product;
echo "<meta property='og:id' content='".$product->get_sku()."'/>";
```

in functions.php file but it does show nothing in content. How i can get SKU of products?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead use the following to add an opengraph meta tag with the product sku on single products:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'opengraph_id_single_product_sku', 9 );
function opengraph_id_single_product_sku(){
    if ( is_product() ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

        echo '<meta property="og:id" content="'.$product->get_sku().'" />';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and Works.

Comment: Thanks! It works,
but unfortunately facebook microdata debugger still shows me:
"A required field is missing: id
Products without "id" information can't be uploaded. Please check that this field is included for each product in a separate, labeled column."

Comment: did you found a solution, i also facing this